# Does UIPickerView's selectRow:inComponent:animated: call pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:?

Tags: uipickerview

Does UIPickerView's `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` call `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`?
Otherwise, can I just call it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not, although it is possible to call it manually.

Answer (score 26):

You do have to call it manually and you do it though the delegate.

```
// In this example the UIPickerView object is in a property
...
self.pickerView.datasource = self;
self.pickerView.delegate = self;

// Selects the row in the specified component
[self.pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

// Manually calls pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
[self pickerView:self.pickerView didSelectRow:0 inComponent:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not call delegate method with swift too, but you can do it manually also. Decision for **swift 3** and **swift 4**:

```
self.pickerView.datasource = self
self.pickerView.delegate = self

self.pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
self.pickerView.delegate?.pickerView?(self.pickerView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
```