# How to call pickerView: didSelectRow: inComponent: without user interaction?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have a 2 components, dependent `pickerView`. I have a preview `UIImageView` that changes each time the user uses the `pickerView` (and triggers the `didSelectRow:inComponent:`). This works just as I expected.

However, I want the `pickerView` to trigger `didSelectRow:` when the app launches, so that there is a Preview the moment the user sees the `UIImageView`. In `viewDidLoad`, when I try this:

```
[self pickerView:picker didSelectRow:row inComponent:component]; // row and component have 0 values.
```

next thing that happens - the `pickerView` shows up blank! Remove this line, and it works perfectly again. I tried this as well:

```
[picker selectRow: row inComponent:component animated:NO];
```

thinking that it will trigger `didSelectRow:` however it doesn't trigger it and my `UIImageView` remain blank.

Any advice on how to call the `didSelectRow:` method without the users help?

**Update**: by the way, the picker is inside another `UIView` (not the main one). In case it matters.

Comment: afaik `– selectRow:inComponent:animated:` should do the trick. what happens if you move your code to `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: it selects the assigned row and component. But didSelectRow: isn't triggered. NSLogged it to make sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`didSelectRow:...` will only be called if a row has been selected by *user interaction*. If you select a row programmatically with `selectRow:...` then you have to add you own logic to update other components like the image view.

The principle is valid for many other delegate functions, such as e.g. `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Yeah... thought so. Just wondered if I'm doing something wrong since I seen a lot of people say that selectRow: triggers didSelectRow:. Thanks. Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments, this what you are looking for then.
[Does UIPickerView's selectRow:inComponent:animated: call pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001738/does-uipickerviews-selectrowincomponentanimated-call-pickerviewdidselectrow)

You have to manually call the `didSelectRow` method.

Comment: I think all of that is done since it does select the row and component I assign, however the code that I have in didSelectRow: isn't executed. And it doesn't even enter didSelectRow (tested with NSLog)

Comment: You have manually call didSelectRow method. It wont automatically call. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001738/does-uipickerviews-selectrowincomponentanimated-call-pickerviewdidselectrow

Comment: Yeah, all of that done. I think Martin R cleared it out for me in the answer above. Thanks for your help though.