# Call moveRowAtIndexPath from TableViewController

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I implemented the body of the method moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    XYZToDoItem *itemToMove = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Moving");
    NSLog( itemToMove.itemName);

    [self.toDoItems removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.toDoItems insertObject:itemToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

I'd like to call this method from TableViewController's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

When I do the rows of the table do move, but the above method doesn't seem to execute. Nothing logs to the console and the items in the array `toDoItems` DO NOT swap.

Here's the body of that method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfLastItem =
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.toDoItems count] - 1) inSection:0];

    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:indexPathOfLastItem];
}
```

How do I get the table view to move rows properly from within the delegate (the TableViewController)?

Comment: Did you implement tableview datasource's protocol method tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're calling the method correctly, since it's not a real delegate method you have to call it on self.

Try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfLastItem =
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.toDoItems count] - 1) inSection:0];

   [self tableView:tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:indexPathOfLastItem];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Moving (or adding, removing) table view rows by code (and not by user interaction) does *not* cause the
data source methods to be called.

If you need the data source method to be executed, you need to call it explicitly:

```
// Move table view row:
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:indexPathOfLastItem];
// Call data source method:
[self tableView:tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:indexPathOfLastItem];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
// Move table view row:
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: indexPathOfLastItem)
// Call data source method:
self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: indexPathOfLastItem)
```

Comment: Does that mean I need to call the two above methods to get the desired result which is 1. move table view row and 2. move items in the datasource?

Comment: @Bonzoq: Yes, as far as I remember. (But I did not test it recently. Perhaps you can make a quick test.)

Comment: Yep, I tested it and otherwise it doesn't work. Am just asking because this didn't look very professional to me but apparently that's how it has to be.

Comment: @Bonzoq: You have the same principle in many places, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075871/1187415 for a similar issue.

Comment: Yep, a very similar issue. I meant this objective-c's pattern of having to call the same thing twice is not very professional. But your answer is very helpful so again thanks:-).

Comment: @Bonzoq: You don't call the same thing twice. The first call is a call to the table view to move the rows. The second call is to *your* data source method to update the data source.

Comment: @MartinR, how do I do this in Swift 3?