# How to programatically select UIPickerView rows and have associated methods execute

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I have an application that uses a two component UIPickerView and executes code based on the various rows selected. Everything works fine when I manually select the row; however, when I try to programatically do it, the row title updates appropriately, but the associated methods do not execute.

I have an NSTimer set up that fires every second and I want to execute the code associated with

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
```

every time this timer fires.

I have tried:

```
[_eventPicker reloadAllComponents];
[_eventPicker selectRow:currentEventComponent inComponent:0 animated:NO];
//my UIPickerView property is named _eventPicker, and I have an int currentEventComponent
//that is set when the user selects the row
```

putting this in my autoRefresh method that is activated by the timer once a second; however, nothing happens. However, when I move away from the current row and back to it manually with my thumb, everything executes appropriately.

So my question is, how do you execute pickerView didSelectRow programatically every second through my autoRefresh timer? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One note I should add would be that I am on iOS Beta 5, Xcode 6 Beta 6, and OS X Yosemite beta 6.

Comment: Oh and the problem is not with the timer... it works fine and executes all the other code within it without issue.

Comment: Anyone? This really has me stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the delegate method yourself of course.

```
[self pickerView: myPickerView 
    didSelectRow:[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:component]
    inComponent:component];
```

If you know what `component` it is, or just 0 if there's only one--you get the picture. If you don't, say you want to go over each component:

```
for (NSInteger component = 0; component < myPickerView.numberOfComponents; ++component)
    [self pickerView: myPickerView 
        didSelectRow:[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:component]
        inComponent:component];
```

You of course could route the `didSelectRow` call to your own method, which you can call yourself more easily than `didSelectRow`. It does seem a little underhanded to "fake" the callback.
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001738/does-uipickerviews-selectrowincomponentanimated-call-pickerviewdidselectrow).